# EquatableView not forcing SwiftUI to use custom implementation of the == function

Tags: swift, xcode, view, swiftui, state

I am unable to use the EquatableView as per the article: [Link1](https://swiftui-lab.com/equatableview/) and [link2](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/01/22/optimizing-views-in-swiftui-using-equatableview/). I expected the "==" function in the TestView to be invoked every time I click on the Button.

Am I missing something here?

```
struct ContentView: View {   
    @State var state = false   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            EquatableView(content: TestView(state: $state))
            Button("Change state", action: {state.toggle()})
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View, Equatable {
    @Binding var state: Bool
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("Test updated")
        Text("TestView state : \(state.description)")
    }
    static func == (lhs: TestView, rhs: TestView) -> Bool {
        //Never printed or invoked
        let _ = print ("lhs == rhs invoked  \(lhs.state) == \(rhs.state)") 
        return lhs.state == rhs.state
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After very helpful response from  Alperen, it shows that “@State” has to be added for == to be triggered. However, passing a "@State" var from parent directly to SubView's "@State" for the same var, as suggested below, makes no sense.

So, I added another variable to TestView “@State var notUsed“ which will not work **unless** "@Binding" is removed. One would also want to compare "@Binding" vars, so to me this is illogical.

My question still remains, am I missing something or is this behaviour by design?

Comment: likely swiftui bypasses the equality check under some conditions due to edge cases that they've found but never bothered to document it.  I'm guess if the child view(conforming to Equatable) has a @ State which can also trigger re-renders, SwiftUI can by pass it because it's seperate from what EquatableView's optimization does.  Thus when you remove @State, it will do the check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Equatable` is used when a view is created, so either it should replace already existed or not. In your example `TestView` is not re-created, because it should not on binding changed - only `body` rendered with new value.

To simulate recreation (for testing purpose) the simplest it to add condition. Equatibility is just a optimisation technic it helps SwiftUI to detect replace existed view instance or not.

Here is updated example to demo Equatable works. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var state = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if state {
               EquatableView(content: TestView(state: $state))
            }
            Button("Change state", action: {state.toggle()})
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View, Equatable {
    @Binding var state: Bool
    init(state: Binding<Bool>) {
        _state = state
        print(">> inited")        // << check if created
    }
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("Test updated")
        Text("TestView state : \(state.description)")
    }
    static func == (lhs: TestView, rhs: TestView) -> Bool {
        //Never printed or invoked
        let _ = print ("lhs == rhs invoked  \(lhs.state) == \(rhs.state)")
        return lhs.state == rhs.state
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! Just to clarify, why did you say "for testing purpose". I wanted to use this to optimise one of the views causing issues.  Why would you not initialise  "_state = state" in production code?

Comment: the problem with this code is that the equatableView re-renders regardless if the equality check is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

That code is working. Can you try this?

[image: SS]

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @State var state = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestView(state: state).equatable()
            Button("Not Change", action: {})
            Button("Change", action: {state.toggle()})
           
        }
    }
}


struct TestView: View, Equatable {
    @State var state: Bool
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("Test updated")
        Text("TestView state : \(state.description)")
    }
    static func == (lhs: TestView, rhs: TestView) -> Bool {
        //Never printed or invoked
        let _ = print ("lhs == rhs invoked  \(lhs.state) == \(rhs.state)")
        return lhs.state == rhs.state
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen that before, If you run it, you will see it doesn't work.Same behaviour,  the == is not invoked.

Comment: @Alperen, you are on to something... I will update my post as response is long. FYI: Also  [the link you sent](https://github.com/kazuhiro4949/SwiftUICatalog/blob/master/SwiftUICatalog/View%20Layout%20and%20Presentation/Sample/EquatableViewSample.swift) originally also did not work as it did not have the "@State".