# How to prevent SwiftUI to rerender the entire tabview when using a Custom Alert view on top of it?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a tab view with 5 tabs. An alert view will be shown at the top when my view model's property gets true? But every time the alert is shown, the entire tab view is redrawn causing high cpu usage.

I want the alert to be shown regardless of which tab the user is in so I did a ZStack on the tab view to show the alert. But how do I prevent SwiftUI to redraw the entire tab view?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView() {
                MiniPlayer(content:
                    BrowseView()
                )
                .tabItem {
                    Group {
                        Image(systemName: "square.grid.2x2")
                        Text("Browse")
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedTab = 0
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
                
                MiniPlayer(content:
                    AllSongsListView()
                )
                .tabItem {
                    Group {
                        Image(systemName: "music.note")
                        Text("Songs")
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedTab = 1
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
                
                MiniPlayer(content:
                    PlaylistsView()
                )
                .tabItem {
                    Group {
                        Image(systemName: "music.note.list")
                        Text("Playlists")
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedTab = 2
                    }
                }
                .tag(2)
                
                MiniPlayer(content:
                    MoreView()
                )
                .tabItem {
                    Group {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        Text("More")
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedTab = 3
                    }
                }
                .tag(3)
            }
            
            Alert()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    }
}

struct Alert: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: Manager
    
    var body: some View {
        if manager.showSuccessAlert {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Successful.")
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .zIndex(1)
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
                    withAnimation {
                        
                        manager.showSuccessAlert = false
                    }
                }
            }
            .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .top), removal: .move(edge: .top)))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old but I found it and a fix while having a similar issue...

While presenting an alert in a view that was not part of the default/main tab, the alert would fire and the app would automatically navigate back to the default tab.

This was fixed after adding tags for each tab.

Example:

```
@State private var selection: Tab = .workout

enum Tab {
    case workout, exercises, history, testing
}

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        WorkoutRootView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Workout", systemImage: "figure.strengthtraining.traditional")
            }
            .tag(Tab.workout)
        
        ExerciseListRootView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Exercises", systemImage: "dumbbell")
            }
            .tag(Tab.exercises)
        
        HistoryRootView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("History", systemImage: "calendar")
            }
            .tag(Tab.history)
```

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to move entire `TabView` into separated view, so that `ZStack` looks like

```
    ZStack {
       TabsContentView()      // << move everything inside !!
       Alert()
    }
```

Comment: Tried your solution and I still still my tab views being recreated so many times with a very high cpu usage of 37%...

Comment: Then it is due to some different code. Consider also equatable, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65351345/12299030.